# Android How to override class in remote package with local class

Tags: java, android, gradle

My app depends on a remote package, which is hosted in a server repository. The package is maintained independently.

Now I want to expand a class in a remote package. I create a local copy of the same class, and make modifications on it for experiment purpose. In this way, I dont need to modify the library, push it to repository and compile my app for every debug cycle.

However, the app compilation still uses the remote class instead of the local extended copy. And report errors.

```
error: cannot find symbol variable XXX_XX1
error: cannot find symbol variable XXX_XX2
```

those variables XXX_XX1 and XXX_XX2 are newly added to the local classA

Remote library repo: org.example.packagename.datamodel.classA

Local source path
.\android\app\src\mock\java\org\example\packagename\datamodel\classA.java

My question is how to ask Android Studio to use the local copy of classA instead of teh remote one during compilation?

**UPDATE**

After a closer examination, only those classes in the unit test folder report errors. And the main program classes do not report errors (yet, maybe it will after unit test classes are compiled).

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileMockDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'. Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Do you own the library?

Comment: @Karakuri I am a contributor, but not the sole owner.

Comment: So you are trying to test changes you've made to the library, but in order to do that you need to compile against your local version rather than the published version you would get from jcenter/maven central/etc. Have I understood your problem correctly?

Comment: Correct. I want to create a local copy, compile and test it. Once it is done, I can introduce the changes to the library project and push it to maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly straightforward way to do this would be to add a module to your test project whose source files are your modified version of the library. You would then remove the binary dependency and replace it with a dependency on this new module. It should look something like this...

In `settings.gradle` add

```
include ':libraryName'
project(':libraryName').projectDir = new File('/path/to/library/sources')
```

In the `build.gradle` for the app

```
// compile 'groupId:artifactId:version' // <-- comment out the published binary
compile project(':shared') // <-- add your local module
```

Do a gradle sync and you should be in good shape. Just remember to **not** commit these changes in your test project when you're done.

---

Another approach I have taken in the past is to use a maven gradle plugin to publish the library to my local maven repository (with a new version name). Then in the test project I would update the version name and also add

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

This might be a bit more complicated but has the advantage of not messing around with modules--you're still pulling in a binary dependency, it's just served locally from your maven repository, not downloaded from the web. You just have to remember **not** to commit any changes you made to the library source and build files related to publishing locally.

Answer (score 0):

You should extent the class in the library (using composition is also an option if the class is final)

```
public class LocalClassA extends RemoteClassA {
}
```

both could be named `ClassA`, as they will be in different packages, but this may lead to confusion.

Comment: Currently, classA is being used extensively in the app, so putting them in different packages requires changing dependencies in dozen of other files. What I am trying to achieve is like choosing a build flavor, but between local classA and remote classA.